# Are there any algorithms that give global optimum for K-Means?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms, k-means

The performance function of K-Means is minimum distance form the observations to the centroid of the closet cluster. For ideal solution we must find the real centroid of each cluster, but in ordinary K-Means algorithm the centroids will be approximated randomly and then iterately refined until converge to local optimum( that sometimes yields poor result) .
 I wonder that are there any method to find the real centroid to yield the global optimum (in the case that time complexity is not concerned).

Comment: Maybe you can try combining it with genetic algorithm instead of using brute force search. That should prune the search space quite substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A trivial example would be brute force search. Simply try all possible assignments of data points to clusters, and pick the assignment that minimizes the cost function. For a slightly improved (but still grossly impractical) version of brute force search, do it in a way that respects the symmetries of the problem. For example, if the same points are assigned to a cluster, it doesn't matter whether this is called cluster "1" or cluster "2", so there's no need to test both. More efficient methods from combinatorial optimization can probably be used, like [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

But, computational complexity can't be ignored in practice. The k-means problem is NP hard, so an algorithm for finding the global optimum in a feasible amount of time in the general case probably can't exist.